# How do I fix error with svelte-kit and aws-amplify?

Tags: node.js, aws-amplify, sveltekit

I'm getting an error with svelte-kit and `@aws-amplify/auth`

`import Auth from '@aws-amplify/auth';` causes the following error:

```
500

global is not defined

node_modules/amazon-cognito-identity-js/node_modules/buffer/index.js@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/@aws-amplify_auth.js?v=fb9b3a59:4766:5
__require2@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/chunk-A2XPJTG4.js?v=fb9b3a59:19:44
@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/@aws-amplify_auth.js?v=fb9b3a59:30155:32
```

I've tried adding this:

```
                resolve({
                    browser: true,
                    preferBuiltins: false,
                    alias: {
                        "./runtimeConfig": "./runtimeConfig.browser"
                    }
                }),
```

but it doesn't seem to do anything. Also I don't know what this `runtimeConfig` is

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult, `global` exist in NodeJS and modern browsers but not in web-workers, but because Svelte heavily uses workers it's problem.
https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/pull/4628 -- This PR introduces `globalThis` but you need to find a way to change this lib.

Or if you want to use it in SSR only (server-side) you should import and put this code for `<script context="module">`.

The main issue here is this library because it depends on NodeJS and is not designed especially for browsers.

Answer (score 0):

The solution from [this Github issue](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/9639#issuecomment-1049158500) fixed it for me... add this to the top of your `app.html` file:

```
<script>
    var global = global || window
    var Buffer = Buffer || []
    var process = process || { env: { DEBUG: undefined }, version: [] }
</script>
```